# C non-blocking send not working

Tags: c++, c, sockets, nonblocking

I'm trying to send the large amount of data to the server which should accept the data and parse it. So as I know, when you `send()` the data in blocking mode in one call, it splits data into chunks and then sends the chunks to the target. But I need to mark each chunk with a small identifier in the beginning of the data (let's say I'm placing a header in each chunk), so I decided to use non- blocking send. I thought, when I do non-blocking send, it sends the max the buffer allows and then returns, leaving the chunking work for me, but it seems that's not happening.

My code is:

```
    struct sockaddr_in target;

    SOCKET connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);  
    target.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);
    target.sin_port = htons(port);

     ULONG NonBlock;
     NonBlock = 1;
     if (ioctlsocket(connection, FIONBIO, &NonBlock) == SOCKET_ERROR)
     {

         return WSAGetLastError();

     }

      fd_set write_fds;

        FD_ZERO(&write_fds);            
        FD_SET(connection, &write_fds);
        struct timeval tv;
        tv.tv_sec=1;
        tv.tv_usec=0;
    int result = connect(connection,(SOCKADDR*)&target,sizeof(target));
    if(result==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            result= select(connection+1,NULL,&write_fds,NULL,&tv);
            printf("connect: result=%d\r\n",result);
            if(result== -1)
            {
                return WSAGetLastError();
            }
            else break;
        }

    }

    //later on

fd_set write_set;
int bytes_sent= 0;
int total_sent = 0;
int length = 0;
char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(header)+data_size); //data_size is the size of the large buffer
memcpy(tmp,packet,sizeof(header));
memcpy(tmp+sizeof(header),data,data_size);


int result;

FD_ZERO(&write_set);
FD_SET(connection,&write_set);

struct timeval time_out;

time_out.tv_sec=0;
time_out.tv_usec=1500;

while(total_sent < data_size)
{
    length= (data_size+sizeof(my_header))-total_sent;

    result = select(connection+1,NULL,&write_set,NULL,&time_out);

    if(result== SOCKET_ERROR) return -1;
    if(result!=0 && FD_ISSET(connection, &write_set))
    {
        bytes_sent = send(connection,tmp,length,0);
    }

    if(bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
    if(bytes_sent > 0)
    {
        //here i need to append a header to the new chunk
    }
    else break;


}
```

So basically my question is: why the send on non-blocking socket, still blocks and doesn't return after sending the first chunk, and acts just like regular blocking send? What i want to achieve is `send()` sending one chunk of data of the length that the system allows, so i put the length of the whole data, assuming that non-blocking send will return after sending the first chunk, because the buffer is to big, to be sent as one block.

**UPDATE** some runnable code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <types.h>

typedef struct hdr{
 uint8_t super_id;
}my_header,*pmy_header;

SOCKET connection;
int start_winsock()
{
    WSADATA check;

    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&check);  
    return result;
}
int create_connection(char* host,int port)
{
     struct sockaddr_in target;

    connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 
    target.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);
    target.sin_port = htons(port);
    int result =    UnblockSocket();
    if(result!=0) return WSAGetLastError();

        fd_set write_fds;
        FD_ZERO(&write_fds);            
        FD_SET(connection, &write_fds);
         struct timeval tv;

        tv.tv_sec=1;
        tv.tv_usec=0;

        result = connect(connection,(SOCKADDR*)&target,sizeof(target));
        if(result==SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
          while(true)
          {
            result= select(connection+1,NULL,&write_fds,NULL,&tv);
            if(result== -1)
            {
                 return WSAGetLastError();
            }
             else break;
        }

    }

    return 0;

}


 int UnblockSocket()
 {
   ULONG NonBlock;
   NonBlock = 1;
   if (ioctlsocket(connection, FIONBIO, &NonBlock) == SOCKET_ERROR)
   {

      return WSAGetLastError();

   }
    return 0;
 }



 int SendMyData(pmy_header header,char * data,int data_size)
 {

    fd_set write_set;
    int bytes_sent= 0;
    int total_sent = 0;
    int length = 0;
    char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(my_header)+data_size);
    memcpy(tmp,packet,sizeof(my_header));
    memcpy(tmp+sizeof(my_header),data,data_size);

    int result;

    FD_ZERO(&write_set);
    FD_SET(connection,&write_set);

    struct timeval time_out;

    time_out.tv_sec=0;
    time_out.tv_usec=1500;

    header->super_id=0xdead;
    while(total_sent < data_size)
    {
        length= (data_size+sizeof(my_header))-total_sent;

        if(result== SOCKET_ERROR) return -1;
        if(result!=0 && FD_ISSET(connection, &write_set))
        {
            bytes_sent = send(connection,tmp,length,0);
        }

            printf("bytes sent per iteration=%d\n",bytes_sent);
        if(bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            return SOCKET_ERROR;
        }
        if(bytes_sent > 0)
        {
         total_sent+= bytes_sent-sizeof(my_header);

         tmp = realloc(tmp,sizeof(my_header)+(data_size-total_sent));


         memcpy(tmp,header,sizeof(my_header));
         memcpy(tmp+sizeof(my_header),data,data_size-total_sent);
        }
        else break;


    }
    free(tmp);
    return total_sent;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     start_winsock();
     int result = create_connection("2.2.2.2",88);
     if(result!=0) { printf("Cannot connect\n"); return 0; }

     pmy_header *header = malloc(sizeof(my_header));

     int buf_size = 500000;
     char buffer_test[buf_size];
     ZeroMemory(buffer_test,buf_size);
     int count=0;
     for(count;count<buf_size;count++)
     {
       strcat(buffer_test,"4");
     }
     result = SendMyData(header,buffer_test,buf_size);

}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using boost::asio instead of doing any major deployments over raw socket. Will save you from almost all the trouble

Comment: Because you are blocking in `select()`?

Comment: @Puciek: It is probably just because I've done more with raw sockets but I actually find doing it that way much easier to read than boost::asio. When boost fails to work it does so in mysterrrrrious ways.

Comment: @ZanLynx while I too come from the "raw socket era", where things like asio were immature, it certainly isn't the case any more. At least not in case of ASIO, as I cannot speak for the whole monster that boost is. It took quite a bit of getting used to, but once you do - it just makes the code shorter, cleaner and less prone to errors.

Comment: No you see, i thought that send won't loop continiously trying to send the whole buffer inside like in blocking mode, i thought it will send as much as possible (probably arount 4-5 kb) and return after, but it still blocks until the whole "length" is sent.

Comment: @Puciek i need to use native winapi.

Comment: @jxh So basically i want the send, to write a one chunk of data and then return, so i can prepare other chunk, but i don't know how much data send can actually write per one turn, so i put the length of a whole data, assuming that non-blocking send would return after sending a first chunk, because the data length is too big, and gets splitted.

Comment: TCP is a **stream-based** protocol.  Whether you're operating in blocking or non-blocking mode, there's no concept of a chunk size of packet size (at the application layer) with TCP.  You just send a bunch of bytes down the pipe, and the receiver reads those same bytes in the same order.  When you ask the OS to send a lot of bytes (more than one MTU's worth), it's either going to block until it's sent them all or queue them all to be sent and return control to the application, depending on whether the socket is blocking or not.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield is there a way i can get the size of data that can be sent as one block? So then i can divide my large buffer to the chunks of that sizes.

Comment: @Vanya not really as it depends on networking performance. Of course you can go ridiculously low, like 1024 bytes or less, but that is going to create a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Puciek what do you recommend to do than? Maybe somehow calculate it according to network? The problem is that i need as minimum overhead as possible.

Comment: @Vanya there is no single solution to it, as networking is never perfect, heck it is almost never even stable so you may be safe sending 4kb chunks most of the time, just to have them suddenly fail for no apparent reason. Simply there are too many moving parts between machines that connect over internet.
Easiest thing to do would be to use a very small chunk, 512b or less (the lower it will be, bigger the chance that it will always go in one stream), but that will be more expensive on the traffic generated.

Comment: How exactly do you conclude that `send()` *blocks until the whole "length" is set*? This is not (always) the case even with `send()` on a blocking socket, let alone a non-blocking one. Do you have a minimal example that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: @user4815162342 well it may be my mistake here, i meant that when i call the `send()` it **LOOPS** until all the `length` bytes are sended, yes i tested my example and it's same behavior on both types of sockets. for example i call `send(socket,buffer,1 234 5 67,0)` it will loop until `1 234 567` bytes gets sent. I thought that if i use non-blocking mode, the `send()` will sent the first chunk of data, because the buffer is too big to be sended as one block, and return the control to me.

Comment: @user4815162342 i tried my example code on a various size data, and it's always the same behavior.

Comment: A socket implementation that behaved like that for non-blocking sockets would be seriously broken. Can you show minimal compilable/runnable code that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: @user4815162342 I edited my main post, please take look at the additional code.

Answer (score 2):

`send()` is not guaranteed to send everything you ask it to send.  It may send less.  You MUST take the return value into account.  If it is less than the amount you requested, you have to call `send()` again to re-send the remaining bytes, before then sending new bytes.  And in the case of non-blocking, you have to take `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` into account as well.

And you don't put on a header on each chunk that `send()` sends.  You put a header on each chunk **you** tell `send()` to send.  You do your own chunking, don't worry about the chunking that TCP does internally.  That is a network implementation, it does not affect your protocol.  The receiver should be paying attention to your chunk headers, calling `recv()` as many times as needed to receive your full header and data to account for TCPs chunking.

Try something more like this instead:

```
SOCKET connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);  
if (connection == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
     return WSAGetLastError();
}

ULONG NonBlock = 1;
in result = ioctlsocket(connection, FIONBIO, &NonBlock);
if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    result = WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(connection);
    return result;
}

struct sockaddr_in target;
memset(&target, 0, sizeof(target));
target.sin_family = AF_INET;
target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);
target.sin_port = htons(port);

result = connect(connection, (SOCKADDR*)&target, sizeof(target));
if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    result = WSAGetLastError();
    if (result != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
    {
        closesocket(connection);
        return result;
    }

    fd_set write_fds;
    FD_ZERO(&write_fds);            
    FD_SET(connection, &write_fds);

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    result = select(0, NULL, &write_fds, NULL, &tv);
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        result = WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(connection);
        return result;
    }

    if (result == 0)
    {
        closesocket(connection);
        return WSAETIMEDOUT;
    }
}
```

```
char *tmp_data = data;
int data_remaining = data_size;

while (data_remaining > 0)
{
    int pkt_data_size = min(data_remaining, 1024); // replace 1024 with whatever maximum chunk size you want...

    int pkt_size = sizeof(header) + pkt_data_size;
    char *pkt = malloc(pkt_size);
    if (!pkt) return -1;

    // fill header as needed...
    memcpy(pkt+sizeof(header), tmp_data, pkt_data_size);

    tmp_data += pkt_data_size;
    data_remaining -= pkt_data_size;

    char *tmp_pkt = pkt;
    while (pkt_size > 0)
    {
        result = send(connection, tmp_pkt, pkt_size, 0);
        if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            result = WSAGetLastError();
            if (result != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                free(pkt);
                return -1;
            }

            fd_set write_set;
            FD_ZERO(&write_set);
            FD_SET(connection, &write_set);

            struct timeval time_out;
            time_out.tv_sec = 5;
            time_out.tv_usec = 0;

            result = select(0, NULL, &write_set, NULL, &time_out);
            if (result != 1)
            {
                free(pkt);
                return -1;
            }

            continue;
        }

        tmp_pkt += result;
        pkt_size -= result;
    }

    free(pkt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your code looks a lot more better, but i have one question. What if the server is asynchronous, and it just receives the packets on let's say some event, and my chunk is gonna split up by the `send()` in two parts, there gonna be 2 fired events `OnSocketData` on the server side, and if the server is asynchronous he won't be able to parse it correctly, that's why im trying to put the headers in each chunk.

Comment: The reason i don't do my own fixed chunked sizes, is because i'm trying to get minimum overhead somehow.

Comment: How the receiver reads on its end is irrelevant. The sender can be blocking and the receiver non-blocking, and vice versa. Blocking vs non-blocking is a programming model, not a networking model. The receiver MUST read your full chunk header first, then read the full chunk data, then read the next full chunk header, and so on. The sender does not need to care how many events and reads it takes the receiver to do that. TCP is a stream-based transport, not a message-based transport. There is not a 1-to-1 correlation between sends and reads. Any TCP receiver needs to be coded to handle that.

Comment: All you really need to do is send your full data size once, followed by your full data, however many sends it takes to do that.  Give `send()` as much data as you have and let it decide how much it can really send. The receiver can then read the data size once, then read the full data, however many reads it takes to do that.

Comment: You don't really need to implement manual chunking in TCP in most cases, unless you have to keep track of how many chunks were sent/receiver (for instance, to resume a broken transfer), or if you just don't know the full data size ahead of time (for instance, if the data is being created while it is being sent).

Comment: If you are chunking your data just to deal with overhead issues, you are doing something wrong.  Let the socket handle that for you.  The sender and the receiver have to agree on the format of the data being sent, the sender has to be prepared to send data in multiple calls to `send()`, and the receiver has to be prepared to read data in multiple calls to `recv()`.  This is basic socket programing 101 stuff.

Comment: When node.js receives data, put it in a buffer somewhere, then check the buffer for full data as needed. If you send the data size as a 4-byte integer preceding the data, then every time node.js fires a read event, put the new data in the buffer, then check if the buffer has at least 4 bytes. If yes, read that integer from the buffer and check if the buffer has at least as many bytes as the integer says. If yes, then you have the full data, otherwise you have to wait for the next read event to put more data in the buffer and check again. This is basic socket programming in any language.

Comment: but what if the data is sent asynchronous, from multiple threads? Like various types of data needs to be handled in one socket asynchronously. The data is gonna get mixed?

Comment: Don't have multiple threads sending data to the same socket at the same time.  You have to synchronize the sends so full packets do not overlap each other, corrupting the communication. Same on the receiving end, don't have multiple threads reading from the same socket at the same time, one thread might end up with data that another thread is waiting for.